# Proving the Zero Vector Exists in a Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces

I have the following definitions for a vector space:

$$[x,y]+[a,b]=[x+a+1, y+b]$$
$$r[x,y]=[rx+r-1,ry]$$

I'm trying to prove the 3rd axiom of addition:

> There exists a zero vector in V such that 0 + u = u for all u

I'm not sure how to go about this. Do I plug in zero to the addition definition above to find the zero vector then add that to [x,y] using the defined addition? Perhaps like this?

$$[1,0] + [x,y] = [x+2, y]$$

However as you can see, the result does does equal [x,y].

Comment: You have to find numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $(x,y)+(a,b)=(x,y)$ and $(a,b)+(x,y)=(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$. So, you need $(x+a+1,y+b)=(x,y)$. Can you work that out?

Comment: so [a,b] = [-1, 0]?

Comment: Looks good to me. Write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: Why then when I add the additive inverse of [x,y] to itself I get: [x,y] + [-x,-y] = [1,0] which is not the above zero vector.

Comment: Because the additive inverse of $(x,y)$ is not $(-x,-y)$.

Comment: Oops. I was thinking it was just the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the zero vector find a vector [r,s] that satisfies the following:
$$[x,y]+[r,s]=[r,s]+[x,y]=[x,y]$$
So in this case:
$$[x,y]=[x+r+1,y+s]$$
Therefore, solving for r and s,
$$[r,s]=[-1,0]$$
And that is the zero vector.